# Why probabilities appear on x-axis ? How to shift the probabilities on y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code I want to plot poisson distribution but the probabilites values are appearing on x-axis they should be on y-axis. How to fix this error?

```
`def Poisson(x):
    return (np.exp(-x)) 

ax2=fig.add_subplot(212)
x = np.linspace(0,5,500)
data =Poisson(x)
hist2,bin_edges2,patches = ax2.hist(data,bins=20,density=True)`
```

[image]

using x as input of the histogram I get the following graph.
[image]

Comment: You are plotting a histogram of the `Poisson(x)`. Do you want to plot `x` versus `Poisson(x)`? If so just do `plt.plot(x, Poisson(x))`

Comment: yes I want x versus Poission(x). But I need this distribution in histogram form.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `orientation` argument to horizontal? `ax2.hist(data,bins=20,density=True, orientation='horizontal')`

Comment: with orientation argument I got the desired result.thanks

Comment: oh no. I strongly doubt that `orientation='horizontal'` gives anything close to a meaningful result, at least if, as you say, you want to plot x versus Poisson(x), and neither if, as you say in the question, you want to see a poissonian distribution, showing probabilities.

Comment: Yes I want to see poisson distribution and with orientation argument i'm getting probabilities along y-axis. So this argument is not suitable then what else will be the solution? because I need this distribution only in histogram form not with plt.plot

Comment: I guess you need to start much more basic... A poisson distribution is a *discrete* probability distribution. This means that (a) your definition is not a poisson distribution, and  (b) it does not make sense to call that function with fractional numbers; or (c) you want some other distribution(?).

Comment: I guess you misunderstand my question. If I use ax.hist(x,bins=20,density=True) i'm not getting histogram in correct form so I used data just to see what I get. Apparently graph shows Poission distribution is appearing on y-axis and I need to reverse the axis.

Comment: And I only want Poisson distribution not other one

Comment: I understand your question, but it asks for the wrong thing. `plt.hist` takes in a data sample and shows the frequency distribution. But here you have no data sample. Instead you have a distribution function (which, as said, is not a poisson distribution right now, check wikipedia for the correct formula). So you cannot use `plt.hist`. Also, as said, it would not make sense to evaluate a discrete distribution at fractional data points.